# (Python) adding a list to another without the brackets

Tags: python

I'm currently making my first project in Python - tic tac toe as i thought it would be a good place to start and I've finally hit a road block.

I've currently got the board setup as a list - Board = [1,2,3...,9] and to reset, Board's contents is deleted and re-entered by a separate list however it also adds the brackets.

Is there a way to grab the contents of a separate list without also grabbing the brackets?

```
if newGame == 'Y' or 'y':
     del Board[:]
     Board.append(startBoard)
     print Board #for testing
 else:
     sys.exit('game over')
```

What I'm getting is looking like this:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
```

Comment: Slightly off topic but variable names are conventionally lower_case/camelCase. See [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend

Comment: `if newGame == 'Y' or 'y'` will always be true. Use `if newGame =='Y' or newGame == 'y'` or `if newGame in ('y', 'Y)` or `if newGame.lower() = 'y'`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `extend`.

```
Board.extend(startBoard)
```

Alternatively you can do:

```
Board = [el for el in startBoard]
```

and omit the `del Board[:]` althogether.

Alternatively you can use the [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module:

```
Board = copy.deepcopy(startBoard)
```

For me the best will be this though:

```
Board = [i+1 for i in xrange(9)]
```

Or the simpler:

```
Board = range(1, 10) # python 2
```

or

```
Board = list(range(1, 10)) # python 3
```

As [zehnpaard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3155195/zehnpaard) suggested in the comments.

Also you can do what [Erik Allik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28147508/4371276) has proposed in his answer.

Comment: The second one may cause issues if there are other references to Board that also need to be updated.  Also it would be simpler to do startBoard[:] instead of using a list comprehension.

Comment: The only reason I dislike the `[:]` is that it makes a shallow copy. For `int`s it's OK, but for complex objects it just won't do. Not that any other than `deepcopy` will.

Comment: if you find yourself needing deepcopy more than rarely, you should consider a rethink :)

Comment: Right, frankly copying objects with mutable state always requires a fair bit of care...  If I may quibble one last time (I promise!) I think your last one would be simpler as `Board = range(1, 10)` in Python 2.x, or `Board = list(range(1, 10))` in Python 3.x.

Comment: @zehnpaard Good point. I do have a thing for LCs, which is why I sometimes use that instead of the simpler `range` version.

Comment: `Board = [el for el in startBoard]` is a shallow copy as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to clear out and modify the contents of a list in-place (as opposed to creating a new fresh list and assigning it back to the variable that holds your old list):

```
board[:] = startBoard
```

which, if nothing that needs to see the latest board contents points to the old list, is functionally equivalent to:

```
board = startBoard
```

you can get an idea of what it means to modify something in-place vs create a fresh copy/instance if you play around a little bit with assigning the same contents to multiple variables without making copies in the process.

Also, note that since `startBoard` in your case is a constant, you want to make sure nothing ever modifies it, so the 2nd example is really a very bad idea. There's also however a 3rd:

```
board = startBoard[:]
```

which is actually by far the best of all three. What it does is make a copy of `startBoard` and assign it to the variable `board` without ever modifying the old list `board` was pointing to. Also, because you're using a copy of `startBoard`, you can be sure your start board is always the same in the future.

Note that these aspects arise only in programming languages or styles where mutable datatypes are used; in Functional Programming, almost nothing ever gets modified so you can completely become ignorant of worrying about causing accidental adverse side-effect by touching something someone else is relying on.

Furthermore: note that copying a list can be done in a multitude of ways in Python; from a high level point of view which I'm currently speaking out for there is little difference though, so `copy.copy(startBoard)` is the same as `[x for x in startBoard)` is the same as `startBoard[:]` etc.

See also the PEP8 which provides you with useful coding conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for x in startBoard:
    Board.append(x)
```